# USB Host + Power support

Tags: java, android, xml, usb-otg, usb-hostcontroller

In a project I am currently working on, I am using a PIPO T9 tablet to run an app that uses the USB port to communicate with a transceiver.  The reason I chose this tablet is because it has a usb port and a 5vDC power input (seemingly) allowing it to be powered while the USB port is in use.  I found out later that only one can be used at a time..  So now I have been searching for a way to either:

- Programattically force the tablet to disable USB host while the app is not being used.  Hopefully allowing the tablet to switch to charging from the 5vDC line, or
- Use an OTG Y cable to charge and get data from the USB port

So far I have tried the OTG Y cable method and it seems that this wont work with the tablet.  When the tablet is off it has no trouble charging but as soon as its switched back on, charging stops.  I have seen some similar questions on here and the recommendation was to use USB Accessory mode but I'm struggling to find out whether this will work with a tablet running 4.42 (NOTE:  This tablet has been Rooted).

As always if anyone has any advice I would hugely, hugely appreciate it.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you still working on this project? I did manage to find a build.prop method `rp.usb_host = 0` but don't think that can be loaded/refreshed programatically.